# Can't get photo to render

Tags: photo, jpeg

In this directory that I made accessible

http://www.comehike.com/img/member_photo/543/

I have two photos.  The jpg can render in a browser, and the jpeg can not.  Any idea why? I am stuck :)

Thanks!

Comment: `full_photo.jpeg:-1Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get:

```
The image “http://www.comehike.com/img/member_photo/543/full_photo.jpeg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

So it would seem the image is corrupted in some way or other.

Search around for JPEG recovery software - it is out there. Depending on what happened to your file to get it into that state, it may or may not be recoverable.

**Update**: I looked at the file in a hex editor, and the tail of it seems to be all zeroes.

Starting at offset 0x5581:

```
.Win_BestPos.204.192.205.200.206  
.205.203.205.Win:7.Error:0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0.2M:222 1M:256 FT:2 .P:2  
05 0 +0.........................  
................................  
................................  
................................  
................................  
................................  
................................  
................................
```

I don't know what it means, or if if `Win:7.Error:...` indicates anything in particular, but everything after that point is zeroed.